# Add hours or minutes to the current time

Tags: c#, datetime

I want to increase time to current time.

For example, I have the time of the problem and the expected time to complete them. How can I add to it?

```
 (DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + ...)
```

Answer (score 63):

You can use other variables:

```
DateTime otherDate = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(25);
DateTime tomorrow = DateTime.Now.AddHours(25);
```

Comment: Didn't know they had days of 25 hours these days :p

Comment: Well 25 is "ONLY A NUMBER" of hours being added to the value.

Comment: @aMazing Except the variable says "tomorrow", but if the time is 23:05 on Monday the new date will be 00:05 on Wednesday, technically "the day after tomorrow".

Answer (score 19):

You can use the operators `+`, `-`, `+=`, and `-=` on a DateTime with a TimeSpan argument.

```
DateTime myDateTime = DateTime.Parse("24 May 2009 02:19:00");

myDateTime = myDateTime + new TimeSpan(1, 1, 1);
myDateTime = myDateTime - new TimeSpan(1, 1, 1);
myDateTime += new TimeSpan(1, 1, 1);
myDateTime -= new TimeSpan(1, 1, 1);
```

Furthermore, you can use a set of "Add" methods

```
myDateTime = myDateTime.AddYears(1);                
myDateTime = myDateTime.AddMonths(1);              
myDateTime = myDateTime.AddDays(1);             
myDateTime = myDateTime.AddHours(1);               
myDateTime = myDateTime.AddMinutes(1);            
myDateTime = myDateTime.AddSeconds(1);           
myDateTime = myDateTime.AddMilliseconds(1);       
myDateTime = myDateTime.AddTicks(1);     
myDateTime = myDateTime.Add(new TimeSpan(1, 1, 1));
```

For a nice overview of even more DateTime manipulations see [THIS](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/CSharpDateManipulation.aspx)

Comment: In a tight loop adding a timespan object is faster than the Add functions if you can reuse the timespan object

Answer (score 5):

You can also add a TimeSpan to a DateTime, as in:

```
date + TimeSpan.FromHours(8);
```

Answer (score 2):

Please note that you may add - (minus) sign to find minutes backwards

```
DateTime begin = new DateTime();
begin = DateTime.ParseExact("21:00:00", "H:m:s", null);

if (DateTime.Now < begin.AddMinutes(-15))
{
    //if time is before 19:45:00 show message etc...
}
```

and time forward

```
DateTime end = new DateTime();
end = DateTime.ParseExact("22:00:00", "H:m:s", null);


if (DateTime.Now > end.AddMinutes(15))
{
    //if time is greater than 22:15:00 do whatever you want
}
```